# Using Wireshark to Capture Traffic Between VMs on a Third VM

Tags: lan, wireshark, ping

I have 3 Ubuntu VMs in VirtualBox. They are in a host-only network (LAN). Now, I turn on the wireshark capturing on VM1, and then on VM2 I ping VM3. I expect to capture the ICMP messages on VM1. However, wireshark captures nothing from the "any" interface. Could you please tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, VMs inside servers are off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [sf].

Comment: @RonMaupin Just curious. Why this is off-topic? I am purely want to do some network experiment. There is no server at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select “Allow VMs” Promiscuous mode for the network adapter.

Answer (score 1):

First, Wireshark need to be listening on one interface. When you open Wireshark, there is a list of availables interfaces on your host, physical NICs and Virtual ones, what you need to do is select the specific virtual interface. With that, the packets must be listed.

Comment: I selected the "any" interface. But still ICMP packets between the other two VMs are not captured.

Comment: @ZillGate, the question really is off-topic here. See [this answer](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/406/8499) from [meta]. You should try to ask it on [sf].